# Parent Child Hierarchy to Return All Descendants with Corresponding Primary ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a parent child hierarchy  table.  I am trying to return a list of all of the child ID's for each child ID.  My table is defined as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Organization_Hierarchy_Test (ORGANIZATION_ID INT, PARENT_ORG_ID INT);
INSERT INTO Organization_Hierarchy_Test (ORGANIZATION_ID, PARENT_ORG_ID)
VALUES(1,0), (2,1), (3,1), (4,2), (5,2), (6,2), (7,3), (8,3), (9,3), (10,3);
```

The results that I am after would look like this:

```
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------------+
| ORGANIZATION_ID | PARENT_ORG_ID | ORIGINAL_ORGANIZATION_ID |
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------------+
|               1 |             0 |                        1 |
|               2 |             1 |                        1 |
|               3 |             1 |                        1 |
|               4 |             2 |                        1 |
|               5 |             2 |                        1 |
|               6 |             2 |                        1 |
|               7 |             3 |                        1 |
|               8 |             3 |                        1 |
|               9 |             3 |                        1 |
|              10 |             3 |                        1 |
|               2 |             0 |                        2 |
|               3 |             0 |                        2 |
|               4 |             1 |                        2 |
|               5 |             1 |                        2 |
|               6 |             1 |                        2 |
|               7 |             1 |                        2 |
|               8 |             1 |                        2 |
|               9 |             1 |                        2 |
|              10 |             1 |                        2 |
|               4 |             0 |                        4 |
|               5 |             0 |                        4 |
|               6 |             0 |                        4 |
|               7 |             0 |                        4 |
|               8 |             0 |                        4 |
|               9 |             0 |                        4 |
|              10 |             0 |                        4 |
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------------+
```

The query that I have written gets me a list of all of the descendants for each `organization_id`, but I can not figure out how to return the same `organization_id` that is in fact related to all of the descendants.

I have tried adding a `group by` and returning the `max` id with little luck.  I have a delivery date tomorrow and I am worried that I am not going to be able to work through this in time.

```sql
with descendants as
  ( select PARENT_ORG_ID, ORGANIZATION_ID, 1 as level
    from Organization_Hierarchy_Test OH
  union all
    select d.PARENT_ORG_ID ,  OH1.ORGANIZATION_ID, d.level + 1
    from descendants as d
      join Organization_Hierarchy_Test OH1 on d.ORGANIZATION_ID = OH1.PARENT_ORG_ID
  ) 
select ORGANIZATION_ID, PARENT_ORG_ID, level
from descendants 
order by level, PARENT_ORG_ID,  ORGANIZATION_ID
```

Any ideas on how to return the original `Organization_ID` along with all of the descendant `organization_id`'s?

I am trying to push this to a tabular model and this will save me loads of time in processing the data.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Why does your desired result have a row with Org_ID 2 and Parent_ID 0?

Answer (score 0):

Change your CTE to simply include an extra column `d.ORGANIZATION_ID AS Orig`:

```
with descendants as
  ( select PARENT_ORG_ID, ORGANIZATION_ID, ORGANIZATION_ID AS Orig, 1 as level
    from Organization_Hierarchy_Test OH
  union all
    select d.PARENT_ORG_ID ,  OH1.ORGANIZATION_ID, d.ORGANIZATION_ID AS Orig, d.level + 1
    from descendants as d
      join Organization_Hierarchy_Test OH1 on d.ORGANIZATION_ID = OH1.PARENT_ORG_ID
  )
```